# N/file - How to unzip file

Tags: file, netsuite, unzip, suitescript

I want to know of there is a way by suitescript to unzip files in file cabinet .

I Download à file with the sftp module but I need to unzip it ...

I looked into the helpcenter and suiteanswer it seems nothing is documented about that

Answer (score 3):

You can use the N/compress module to unzip a file:

```
define(['N/file', 'N/compress'], function(file, compress){
    var zipped = file.load({id:'id_from_file_cabinet_file'});
    var unzipped = compress.gunzip({file:zipped}); //should be able to unzip a single zipped file but will not handle a zipped directory
    // name and save it or process the contents:
    var txt = unzipped.getContents();
    // or for a large file: use a reader or line iterator
    ...
});
```

If you have a folder to unzip you can't use any native Netsuite libraries. The way I would handle this would be to send the zipped file to a lambda function that would unzip the folder and return the file to the calling script. There are a lot of systems/services that you can use for that.

If your file is sourced by someone placing the file into an SFTP folder and then  you retrieve it you could possibly set up an S3 backed SFTP service and use S3's lambda triggers to process the file and send any parts of interest to a RESTlet. I've done that for a couple of projects and it works pretty well.

Comment: In my case it's a folder. When I try with compress module I get the following error : "error","code":"COMPRESS_API_DECOMPRESS_ERROR","details":"Failed to decompress file: '.folder_20210713.zip'"

Comment: For a folder you'd need to handle it differently. I edited my answer to include a possible solution.

Comment: @Millet Antoine did you achieved unzipping a zip folder.

Comment: @bknights when we try to upload a ZIP folder using advance add option in file cabinet there is a unzip check box can't we do that through script(Ik that files aren't like record in NS).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using external JS library like JSZip. I'm not sure if this will help you, but you can check how I do it with JSZip here https://github.com/gmihaylov/netsuite-zip-file-reader